# Make entire div a link or only the headline and work with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, usability

Imagine a blog with related articles that show a bit of a teaser like so:

```
<div class="teaser">
    <h2>Fancy article</h2>
    <p>In this awesome article, I talk about the virtues of HTML and JavaScript.</p>
</div>
```

If you want to **allow a click on the entire teaser**, which approach would you follow?

### 1. `<a>` in `<h2>` – place the link in the headline like so:

```
<div class="teaser">
    <h2><a href="fancy-article/">Fancy article</a></h2>
    <p>In this awesome article, I talk about the virtues of HTML and JavaScript.</p>
</div>
```

and trigger a click on the link via JS, when anything within the teaser is clicked.

**Advantages:**

- Link has a clear target for Google and/or usability assisting devices (such as screen readers) and isn't "polluted" with the teaser text

**Disadvantages:**

- Doesn't show link target in status bar, if the user doesn't move their mouse over headline

### 2. `a` around `div.teaser` – the entire div is placed within an `a` tag like that:

```
<a href="fancy-article/">
    <div class="teaser">
        <h2>Fancy article</h2>
        <p>In this awesome article, I talk about the virtues of HTML and JavaScript.</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

This is valid since HTML5 (I think).

**Advantages:**

- Status bar shows link target
- Easy setup
- Clickable area is entirely clear
- No JS

**Disadvantages:**

- Link text is polluted with teaser text, which might be bad for screen readers and for SEO reasons

What would you do from a usability/SEO/semantic perspective?

Comment: Not hard or uncommon to make a headline visually appear to be a link. You can't use `#2` if you put any links in article content either and `<p>` does not belong inside `<a>`

Comment: This is not true for HTML5. You CAN put `p` inside `a`. Check out my answer for a more detailed explanation and also the quote from w3c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer option 2. But keep in mind that `a` is an `inline` element, where `div` `h2` and `p` are block elements.

Therefore, you should make the `a` to a block element to before adding further styles. From the HTML5 point of view, it's perfectly fine imo.

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

a.blockyLink {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="fancy-article/" class="blockyLink">
    <div class="teaser">
        <h2>a is block</h2>
        <p>In this awesome article, I talk about the virtues of HTML and JavaScript.</p>
    </div>
</a>

<br /><br />

<a href="fancy-article/">
    <div class="teaser">
        <h2>a is inline</h2>
        <p>In this awesome article, I talk about the virtues of HTML and JavaScript.</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

[Here's what W3C says:](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-a-element.html)

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links). This example shows how this can be used to make an entire advertising block into a link:

```
<aside class="advertising">
 <h1>Advertising</h1>
 <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=1929&amp;pubid=1422">
  <section>
   <h1>Mellblomatic 9000!</h1>
   <p>Turn all your widgets into mellbloms!</p>
   <p>Only $9.99 plus shipping and handling.</p>
  </section>
 </a>
 <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=375&amp;pubid=1422">
  <section>
   <h1>The Mellblom Browser</h1>
   <p>Web browsing at the speed of light.</p>
   <p>No other browser goes faster!</p>
  </section>
 </a>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thanks so far, but what about the implications for SEO and screen readers? Ideas?

Comment: I think adding a title attribute to the link should be considered.